# Unable to access properties of a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a ViewModel that will be used with the home page View. The ViewModel has some properties like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; }
}
```

In the Home Controller I'm creating an instance of HomeViewModel and then setting the properties of the HomeViewModel before sending it to the Home View like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeViewModel homeVM = new HomeViewModel();
        NewsReader newsReader = new NewsReader();

        homeVM.NewsItems = newsReader.GetNewsItems();

        return View(homeVM);
    }
```

And then in the View I'm trying to do this:

```
   @foreach(var item in Model.NewsItems)
    {
        @Html.Display(m => m.Title)
    }
```

However I'm getting:

```
ViewModels.HomeViewModel does not contain a definition for NewsItems
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I fix it?

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Site.Services.News;

using Site.Models;
using Site.ViewModels;
using Site.DAL;
using Site.Services.Products;

namespace Site.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private DashboardContext db = new DashboardContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HomeViewModel homeVM = new HomeViewModel();
            NewsReader newsReader = new NewsReader();

            homeVM.NewsItems = newsReader.GetNewsItems();

            //NewsReader newsReader = new NewsReader();
            //var newsItems = newsReader.GetNewsItems();


            return View(homeVM);
        }
```

Heres the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Site.ViewModels.HomeViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <p class="lead">Overview</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Customers</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Sales</h2>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("View »", "Index", "SalesRecords", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>News</h2>

        @foreach(var item in Model.NewsItems)
        {
            @Html.Display(item.Title)
        }

        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Read »", "Index", "News", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible that GetNewsitems() is returning null? The code you have posted looks fine

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of is that your view `@Model` declaration is pointing to a different `HomeViewModel` that doesn't have a `NewsItems` property?

Comment: In fact the error message seems to suggest `HomeViewModel` is a nested class of `ViewModels`? (Unless the error is showing the namespace. but it would be odd to start with `ViewModels.`). But the class you're creating an instance of in the controller does not appear to be a nested class

Comment: Added file structure

Comment: Just to confirm, you're saying there is only 1 class in your solution called 'HomeViewModel'? It might be worth doing a Ctrl + F on 'class HomeViewModel'

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the top of your view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to suggest that the view is pointing to a different `HomeViewModel` type, that I assume doesn't have the `NewsItems` Property.

The view's `@Model` declaration seems to be pointing at nested class: `ViewModels.HomeViewModel`

But the `HomeViewModel` object that you are using in the controller is not a nested type.

**UPDATE**

As per your update, I can see that your view is indeed pointing to a different type; `IEnumerable<HomeViewModel>` rather than `HomeViewModel`.

Comment: The HomeViewModel is part of the Site.ViewModels

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the top of your view code?

Comment: That's the Controller code - I'd like to see the View's code, specifically the @Model reference

Comment: Your view is referencing a list of `HomeViewModel` =) You need to remove the IEnumerable

Comment: i.e. `@model Site.ViewModels.HomeViewModel`

Comment: Damn! As you can tell I'm pretty new at all this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your view is

```
@model IEnumerable<Site.ViewModels.HomeViewModel>
```

but your controller sends

```
HomeViewModel homeVM = new HomeViewModel();
return View(homeVM);
```

ie they are not the same type

try changing your view to

```
@model Site.ViewModels.HomeViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
@foreach(var item in Model.NewsItems)
{
    @Html.Display(m => m.Title)
}
```

To

```
@foreach(var item in Model.NewsItems)
{
    @Html.Display(m => item.Title)
}
```

Comment: Still same problem as before

Comment: simply use @Html.Display(item.Title)

Comment: or `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title)`

Comment: No none of these work I still get an error about no definition for NewsItems

Comment: The above seems to be addressing a separate problem to the question

Comment: Check whether the type of the "homeVM" object and the viewmodel  thats is defined on the ".cshml" page are same. I guess these two are referring to two different models.